# AWS Glue joining

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am new to AWS Glue and trying to join two Redshift SQL queries but not sure how we can have only selected fields as my main table has more than 1000 fields.
Below is the query which I am trying to make in Glue.

```
SELECT v.col1, 
       v.col2, 
       s.col3 
FROM 
(
   SELECT col1,
          col2 
   FROM t1 
   WHERE col1 > 0 
) v 
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT col1, 
          col3 
   FROM t2 
   WHERE col1 > 0 
   GROUP BY col1
) s 
ON v.col1 = s.col1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing in Python, I would either use Spark sql or use pysparks join functions.

For Spark SQL

```
1) Convert to a Apache Spark DataFrame using the toDF() function.
2) Make the Spark Data Frame Spark SQL Table using createOrReplaceTempView().
Then run sql and to what you posted above.
```

OR

Use PySpark

```
left_join = t1.join(t2, t1.col1 == t2.name,how='left')
left_join.filter(col('col1' > 0)) # Then filter afterwards
```

Would that work for you?